# Scopes when securing API using Azure web app Easy Auth

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

When securing API web apps using Azure App Service Authentication (easy auth), how do I access the scopes of the current user request?

When using JwtBearer middleware, it is done like this

```
var scopes = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope")?.Value;

if (scopes != null
  && scopes.Split(' ').Any(s => s.Equals("app.read"))) ...
```

But when I comment out the middleware code and only rely on easy auth, there are no scopes.

Comment: It would seem you've got an `id_token` not a `token` aka an access token.  I assume you've been here: https://easyauth.azurewebsites.net/?  How are calling your web api?

Comment: That link refers to Easy OAuth, which is different from Azure App Service Authentication a.k.a "easy auth". But yes, you're right, although access_token is received from B2C, it is lost when auth flow passes through "easy auth" callback, so what I must've ended up trying was the id_token as that was the only token found from /.auth/me.

Comment: They are one in the same .  See this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7035#issuecomment-380951155).